# Firebase Notification Icon and Ringtone is not working when application gets logout and force close. It Occurs only above Lollipop version device

Tags: android, firebase, android-notifications

I am able to receive notifications with icons and sounds when the user is logged in and when the user logout and force close the application the notification is received without icon and sounds(but a white square is been displayed as icon).

**The problem is only above Lollipop version devices like Nexus.**

I here by attached my code.

```
public class FireMsgService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    private JSONObject jObject;

    private String joborder_id, sendout_id;
    private Integer navigation;
    Intent intent;

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
        String title = remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle();
        String message = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();
        String dataResponse = remoteMessage.getData().toString();
        try {
            jObject = new JSONObject(dataResponse);
            if (jObject != null) {
                JSONObject responseObject = jObject.getJSONObject("response");
                navigation = responseObject.getInt("navigation");
                joborder_id = String.valueOf(responseObject.getInt("joborder_id"));
                sendout_id = String.valueOf(responseObject.getInt("sendout_id"));
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (navigation == 1) {
            if (SessionStores.getLogInState(this).equalsIgnoreCase("0")) {
                intent = new Intent(this, SignIn.class);
            } else {
                intent = new Intent(this, PositionDetailScreenRefactor.class);
                intent.putExtra("id", joborder_id);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            }
        } else if (navigation == 2) {
            if (SessionStores.getLogInState(this).equalsIgnoreCase("0")) {
                intent = new Intent(this, SignIn.class);
            } else {
                intent = new Intent(this, ScheduleMeeting.class);
                intent.putExtra("sendout_id", sendout_id);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            }
        } else if (navigation == 3) {
            if (SessionStores.getLogInState(this).equalsIgnoreCase("0")) {
                intent = new Intent(this, SignIn.class);
            } else {
                intent = new Intent(this, PositionAcceptenceScreen.class);
                intent.putExtra("sendout_id", sendout_id);
                intent.putExtra("joborder_id", joborder_id);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            }
        } else if (navigation == 0) {
            if (SessionStores.getLogInState(this).equalsIgnoreCase("0")) {
                intent = new Intent(this, SignIn.class);
            } else {
                intent = new Intent(this, NotificationScreen.class);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            }
        }
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 1410, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        Uri sound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(getNotificationIcon())
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(message)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(sound)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(1410, notificationBuilder.build());
    }
    private int getNotificationIcon() {
        boolean useWhiteIcon = (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP);
        return useWhiteIcon ? R.drawable.notificationlogo : R.drawable.app_icon;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

https://clevertap.com/blog/fixing-notification-icon-for-android-lollipop-and-above/ and for making pic transparent use this [link](http://www141.lunapic.com/editor/?action=transparent)

Comment: I tried this it works fine when the user is logged in session. 
I get blank icon while user logged out and force close the application.

Answer (score 0):

From Firebase 9.8.0 it works fine

that means 
Add this dependency in you Gradle App

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.8.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.8.0'
```

and in Manifest.

```
 <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
            android:resource="@drawable/ic_stat_notify" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
            android:resource="@color/colorAccent" />
```